# System-wide desktop file installation for unpackaged software

Tags: debian, xdg

I want to configure a locally installed **unpackaged** application to be started via applications menu in Debian. It should be independent of desktop environment and visible to all users. I don't want to install any Gnome or KDE dependencies to perform this simple task.

Which command is more suited to install desktop files in my case?

Possible candidates:

- xdg-desktop-icon
- desktop-file-install

What is the the difference between these?

Answer (score 1):

`xdg-desktop-icon` adds an icon to the current user's desktop, it doesn't add entries to all users' menus.

`desktop-file-install` installs `.desktop` files to the user's applications directory when run as a non-`root` user, and to `/usr/share/applications` if run as `root` (thanks for pointing that out), so you can use that to install an application entry in the menu.

You could also install an application in the menu for all users manually; all that's needed it to create a `.desktop` file and copy it to `/usr/share/applications`.

For non-packaged applications you can also use `/usr/local/share/applications` (creating it if necessary); that works at least in Debian 8. So with `desktop-file-install` you'd run (as `root`)

```
desktop-file-install --dir=/usr/local/share/applications ...
```

See ["Howto desktop files"](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Howto_desktop_files/) and [the relevant specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) for more details.

Comment: First link recommend desktop-file-install, but I believe packaged application is implied

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed my answer. Regarding packaged applications being implied, you're right in that `/usr` outside `/usr/local` is supposed to be managed entirely by packages, so `/usr/share/applications` shouldn't be used for non-packaged application entries.

Comment: wrong for user context too; on Ubuntu/Debian it tries always to install into system directories.

Comment: @TheDiveO it worked back in 2015 when I wrote this; but you’re right, it doesn’t work now...